# How do I get tinymce edit windows to look like the site pages in django mezzanine?

Tags: django, tinymce, mezzanine, django-tinymce

Mezzanine is looking good and working well but I'm having trouble when I edit some blog posts and pages because the tinymce edit window displays in its own style using a very small font. I need it to be at least roughly WYSIWYG.

Following the documentation for [django_tinymce](http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#configuration) and for [tiny mce](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x%3acontent_css), I set up my settings thus:

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {'theme': "simple",
                          'relative_urls': False,
                          'content_css': ','.join([os.path.join(STATIC_URL, path) for path in [
                              "css/animate.css",
                              "css/bootstrap.min.css",
                              "css/font-awesome.min.css",
                              "css/jquery.bxslider.css",
                              "css/main.css",
                              "css/mezzanine.css",
                              "css/bootstrap-theme.css",
                              "css/custom-styles.css"]]),
                          'theme_advanced_font_sizes': "10px,12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
                          'font_size_style_values': "10px,12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px"}
```

This has no effect. I'm not sure how to dig in and see what is going on. The above css files are all available when I type in the generated urls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mezzanine and django_tinymce have nothing to do with each other - presumably you're configuring software that isn't even installed.

From the Mezzanine docs:

> If you’d only like to customize the TinyMCE options specified in its JavaScript setup, you can do so via the TINYMCE_SETUP_JS setting which lets you specify the URL to your own TinyMCE setup JavaScript file.

http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/admin-customization.html#wysiwyg-editor

Not quite as straight-forward as django-tinymce, but you can get to the same result.

Also note that the styles (such as the tiny font mentioned) have since been updated in the development version of Mezzanine, so if you build against that you might not even need to configure things:

https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/commit/6dff64bf058ac0e83c3c313b4167f8bbd1ac9560

Comment: Doh! Thanks, that explains why nothing was happening. I'll configure it anyway because I want to see the display as wysiwig. Results are at www.paulwhippconsulting.com.

Comment: Perfect. Now I have WYSIWYG.